# No module named 'socks'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests, socket, socks
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socks'
```

I have tried ***pip install socks***, and followed instructions of other stackoverflow posts but none of them worked. I'm working on pycharm right now and I have also installed socks and socket on there, in fact, it ***does show*** I have installed it. And yes, I do have it on the ***right interpreter***.

How can I solve this?

OS: Latest version of Ubuntu

Comment: if you do have it installed then it sounds like you _do not_ have the right interpreter as you state

Comment: OK, i checked it again and it shows that socks is version 0 and as description it says that it should be deleted as soon as possible, which is strange. I deleted it and installed another package instead and it looks like it's fixed now? I'm gonna test it and i'll let you know in a minute

Comment: read my answer @Rightfully

Comment: Thanks, i tried your solution, the module error is fixed, thank you!

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm new here! I have clicked worked now.

Comment: The `socks` packages on PyPI has version number `0` and a total size of 618 bytes. I doubt that it is of any good.

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you mean to install PySocks so do `pip install PySocks`
[pypi docs for PySocks](https://pypi.org/project/PySocks/)
`pip install socks` installs something different [pypi docs for socks](https://pypi.org/project/socks/)

Comment: this installs `socks.py` and `sockshandler.py` into your `Lib\site-packages` folder. I still can't get `import socks` to work as it doesn't seem to find it.

Answer (score 5):

`pip install pysocks`

should fix it for you.

[Pysocks website](https://pypi.org/project/PySocks/)